# How to change a picture after pressing on it using MouseListener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, mouselistener

My Images are in  JLabels and they follow a MouseListener but I don't know what to add in the mousePressed(Event e) method to change the JLabel with another image ??

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question with a working code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JLabel has `setIcon()` method. You can use it to change the picture your label shows.

For example:

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(imageOne);
myLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdaper() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("image2.png");
        myLabel.setIcon(image2);
    }
});
```